# Cleaning up multiple IF statements in the code

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

My code is like this

```
string statuscodeToSet;

if (xElementAltItem != null && (generalstatuscode.Contains(currentstatuscode) && xElementAltItem.Value.Trim() =="null"))
{
    statuscodeToSet = "1";
}
if (xElementupdateDate != null && (xElementAltItem != null && (generalstatuscode.Contains(currentstatuscode) && xElementAltItem.Value.Trim() == "null") && xElementupdateDate.Value == "01-JAN-2099"))
{
    statuscodeToSet = "2";
}
if (xElementupdateDate != null && (xElementAltItem != null && (generalstatuscode.Contains(currentstatuscode) && xElementAltItem.Value.Trim() == "null") && xElementupdateDate.Value != "01-JAN-2099"))
{
    statuscodeToSet = "3";
}
if (xElementAltItem != null && (generalstatuscode.Contains(currentstatuscode) && xElementAltItem.Value.Trim() != "null"))
{
    statuscodeToSet = "4";
} 
if (xElementAltItem != null && (currentstatuscode == "Act-NotOrd" && xElementAltItem.Value.Trim() == "null"))
{
    statuscodeToSet = "5";
}
```

Obviously I don't think this is the best way to code this.Is there any way I can shorten this code and looks it more standard. May be using Linq

Comment: Are these meant to be `else if`'s? Because it will stack logically at the moment. Is that desired behaviour? Also, "Optimised" is a bad word for this. You're asking for it to be cleaned up. Clean Code != Optimized code.

Comment: First take common comparision condition in your case first check for xElementAltItem != null then use else if,

Comment: You could try at least to make things easier for everybody and use shorter variable names, and format the code to fit in single lines...

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Closeley checking on first and second condition, You can understand why its all if not else if.eventhough first case is true I need to check second and if second also comes true I need to execute second case. Probably this may not the correct way to design this code.you can suggest any edits. I am always open to suggestions.

Comment: @Athul Not having an else-if smells like "hard to maintain" since there is only one possible final state; the code should be organized to reflect that, IMOHO. Anyway, the quickest cleanup is to eliminate duplicate conditions as Kamlesh indicated. Secondary cleanup (e.g. if-else) can be done by *nesting* conditionals where appropriate. Those changes should make it a good bit easier to read/maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be the simplest possible, but I don't think this is simple.

```
if (xElementAltItem != null)
{
    if (xElementAltItem.Value.Trim() == "null")
    {
        if (generalstatuscode.Contains(currentstatuscode))
        {
            statuscodeToSet = "1";
            if (xElementupdateDate != null)
            {
                if (xElementupdateDate.Value == "01-JAN-2099")
                {
                    statuscodeToSet = "2";
                }
                if (xElementupdateDate.Value != "01-JAN-2099")
                {
                    statuscodeToSet = "3";
                }
            }
        }
        if ((currentstatuscode == "Act-NotOrd"))
        {
            statuscodeToSet = "5";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (generalstatuscode.Contains(currentstatuscode))
        {
            statuscodeToSet = "4";
        } 
    }
}
```

You really need to tease out the logic here by creating some meaningful variable names to make the conditions read like English otherwise your code is vulnerable to bugs.

Answer (score 2):

Update: I seem to have introduced a difference wrt the original in the handling of the update date as it appears I collapsed three states into two (whoops!) which appears in steps #2/#3. In any case, I believe the following is still an applicable template to follow.

---

#### Step #1: Eliminate the duplicate conditional checks with variables.

This simplifies the conditionals greatly and makes it easier to see what is "supposed" to happen.

```
var nullAlt = xElementAltItem != null ? xElementAltItem.Value.Trim() == "null" : false;
var hasCurrentStatus = generalstatuscode.Contains(currentstatuscode);
var updateDate = xElementupdateDate != null ? xElementupdateDate.Value : "";

if (nullAlt && hasCurrentStatus)
{
    statuscodeToSet = "1";
}
if (nullAlt && hasCurrentStatus && updateDate == "01-JAN-2099"))
{
    statuscodeToSet = "2";
}
if (nullAlt && hasCurrentStatus && updateDate != "01-JAN-2099"))
{
    statuscodeToSet = "3";
}
if (!nullAlt && hasCurrentStatus)
{
    statuscodeToSet = "4";
} 
if (nullAlt && currentstatuscode == "Act-NotOrd")
{
    statuscodeToSet = "5";
}
```

#### Step #2: Group the separate conditions and rewrite the code with "nested" and "else" conditionals.

This should eliminate most (if not all) of the duplicate checks and provide "one path" through the entire conditional structure. The order of grouping depends upon the logical importance of each condition and how well it eliminates duplicates between branches. In this case the code is grouped by `nullAt` and then `hasCurrentState`.

```
// ..
if (nullAlt) { 
  if (hasCurrentStatus) {
    statuscodeToSet = "1";
    if (updateDate == "01-JAN-2099"))
    {
      statuscodeToSet = "2";
    } else { /* updateDate != "01-JAN-2099" */
    {
      statuscodeToSet = "3";
    }
  } else if (currentstatuscode == "Act-NotOrd")
  {
    statuscodeToSet = "5";
  }
} else { /* !nullAlt */
  if (hasCurrentStatus)
  {
    statuscodeToSet = "4";
  } 
}
```

#### Step #3: Place the code into a separate function and return the result.

That is, don't assign the "status" to a variable. Besides maintaining tidy code separation and self-documentation, this is useful because then invalid code paths/logic can be more easily spotted.

For instance, `return "1"` makes no sense where it is located (as then neither status "2" nor "3" could be reached and if it removed then status "1" is never returned!) and there are some "otherwise" cases not handled.

```
string GetStatusCode (..) {
  // ..
  if (nullAlt) { 
    if (hasCurrentStatus) {
      // whoops! What was this doing??
      return "1";
      if (updateDate == "01-JAN-2099"))
      {
        return "2";
      } else { /* updateDate != "01-JAN-2099" */
      {
        return "3";
      }
    } else if (currentstatuscode == "Act-NotOrd")
    {
      return "5";
    } else {
      // return what here?
    }
  } else { /* !nullAlt */
    if (hasCurrentStatus)
    {
      return "4";
    } else {
      // return what here?
    } 
  }
}
```

At this final stage, the usage of the intermediate variables could be reverted without losing much readability because the duplicate expressions have been eliminated. However, excepting in cases where lazy evaluation is strictly required, separate variables are perfectly valid - use them if they make the code cleaner.

Using enumerations or constants would also be an improvement: a status value of `NeedsUpdate` is more informative than `"3"`.

I recommend keeping it *simple* and following the approach outlined above.

YMMV.

Comment: Personally I find the result of your Step 1 is the most readable of all solutions to this question.

Comment: @fabsenet While I agree that step #1 is a good bit more readable than the original, I *usually* avoid [complex] flat if-statements when there is only one output state. In this case, I didn't even see the issue with state "1" until I worked out step #2. (Going all the way to step #3 is my preference and a pattern is fairly common in my code.)

Comment: @fabsenet Whoops. It looks like I introduced a difference with the initial variable capture .. anyway ..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (xElementAltItem == null)
    return;
statuscodeToSet = "1";
if (xElementAltItem.Value.Trim() == "null")
    if (generalstatuscode.Contains(currentstatuscode))
        statuscodeToSet = xElementupdateDate != null && xElementupdateDate.Value != "01-JAN-2099" ? "3" : "2";
    statuscodeToSet = currentstatuscode == "Act-NotOrd" ? "5" : null;
else
    statuscodeToSet = generalstatuscode.Contains(currentstatuscode) ? "4" : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

@Samiey Mehdi  is on the right track.

But this is not about if statements. it is about building a rules engine, or putting your code in a position to build a rules engine

Inverting Samiey code:

```
    statuscodeToSet = "1";
if (xElementAltItem == null) return;

return xElementAltItem.Value.Trim() != "null"
        ? generalstatuscode.Contains(currentstatuscode) ? "4" : null
        : null;

return !generalstatuscode.Contains(currentstatuscode)
        ? currentstatuscode == "Act-NotOrd" ? "5" : null
        : statuscodeToSet;

return generalstatuscode.Contains(currentstatuscode)
        ? xElementupdateDate != null && xElementupdateDate.Value != "01-JAN-2099" ? "3" : "2"
        : statuscodeToSet;
```

Now each of the "return"s is a  rule.

We can put each in it own interface/class.

Put those interfaces/classes into a factory

call the factory to get the list of rules

loop thru the list to execute the rules

That enumeration can be a foreach or a Parellel.foreach

There by making our code

- Clean
- Testable
- Fast